# Android why can't I see ic_launcher-web.png

Tags: android

I'd like a splashscreen simply but I can't see ic_launcher-web.png (which contains my own picture) when launching the App why ?

Does it mean I can't use this to create a splashscreen and I have to code a splashscreen myself ?

Comment: There's no need for code - the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ic_launcher-web.png` is used only by the Google Play Store.
It's placed outside your resource folders (it's near your manifest file), so it's **unreachable**.

If you really want to use it, just copy it in a drawable folder (/res/drawable-xyz).

**[EDIT]**

That picture is sized 512*512 px at 72 dpi, so you may want to resize it to better fit the different resolutions of the various devices your app will run on.

For your reference, here's a good lecture on supporting multiple screen on Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: OK but in res that wouldn't give me a splashscreen ?

Comment: ... pardon? what do you mean? If you already have a splash screen and you want to add the picture to it, place the picture in a `/res/drawable` folder and then refer it. Easy. Or I didn't understand your sub-question. You can create the missing drawable folders as per your needs (i.e.: drawable-xxhdpi)